# Heroku Deployment Problem with status code 127 and node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, package.json

I am trying to deploy my app on Heroku with node.js. App is running fine on my local but when I try to deploy it on Heroku it gives the following error:

```
2022-03-13T00:12:16.474210+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/boot`
2022-03-13T00:12:17.528943+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/boot: No such file or directory
2022-03-13T00:12:17.679770+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2022-03-13T00:12:17.738233+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-03-13T00:13:07.280433+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sopra-fs22-gulec-egeonu-client.herokuapp.com request_id=73dc7825-de2b-4a24-bf3f-4d7bfe67ec60 fwd="213.55.224.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-13T00:13:07.460574+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sopra-fs22-gulec-egeonu-client.herokuapp.com request_id=d29010bf-9c0b-4e27-b902-9540d393f667 fwd="213.55.224.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-13T00:13:41.656858+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sopra-fs22-gulec-egeonu-client.herokuapp.com request_id=91ecbc00-ee15-4eed-bbfd-c3d3af522548 fwd="213.55.224.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-13T00:13:41.867824+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sopra-fs22-gulec-egeonu-client.herokuapp.com request_id=cfd378e9-ab85-46a3-b636-3e4fac1140ad fwd="213.55.224.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

My Proficle is this:

```
web: bin/boot
```

and package.json

```
{
  "name": "sopra-fs22-client-template",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-gyp": "^8.4.1",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-datetime-picker": "^3.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "serve -s build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

I also checked the other posts and tried other things as well but I don't know where else to check thank you very much.

Comment: Well, what is `bin/boot` supposed to be? Do you have a `bin/boot` file, or do you somehow build one during deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your Procfile to this

```
web: npm run start
```

Comment: It gives the following error :`2022-03-13T00:45:29.537411+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command npm run start
2022-03-13T00:45:30.529777+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-03-13T00:45:30.529791+00:00 app[web.1]: > sopra-fs22-client-template@0.1.0 start
2022-03-13T00:45:30.529791+00:00 app[web.1]: > serve -s build
2022-03-13T00:45:30.529791+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-03-13T00:45:30.533924+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: serve: not found `

Comment: your dependencies may not be installed on the heroku side. Try npm install && npm run build inside the heroku-postbuild script. Also, if this is just a react app with no backend, you can publish it easliy following this link -> https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration

Comment: I have a backend server and thank you very much when I add npm install && npm run build && npm install -g serve to heroku-postbuild script it worked

Answer (score 0):

I've deleted my node modules and copy the dependencies from package-lock.json and paste it into package.json

I found out that nodemon wasn't in the dependencies section, then I added: "start": "nodemon index.js", in scripts, npm i, again and deploy it, it worked !